# Pass an argument to another html page with click function javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page page1.html and redirect it to another page page2.html using redirect function:

page1

```
...
<a id="link1" href="page2.html" hidden></a>
<input type="button" name="load1" id="load1" onclick="redirect1(2020);" value="page2"/>

...

<script>
function redirect1(argument1){
    $('#link1')[0].click(function(){
     }); 
}
</script>
...
```

page2

```
...
<input name="test2" id="test2" value="0"/>
...
```

What I'd like to do is to pass an argument1 to page2 and asign it to input test2 value.
I cannot find a connection between these two pages since the link is broken when a page is redirected. Any idea?

Comment: Try using localStorage or history stack/locationhash

Comment: of course, the original files are not like this, I modified them for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

1. Using query param
2. Using data(localStorage, sessionStoreage)

// Using Localstorage

```
// Page 1

$('#load1').click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem("username", "some name")
});

// page 2

$(function() {
  // get data
  const username  = localStorage.getItem("username")
})
```

**Using Query param**

```
// If data is small, can use query params

// Page 1
$('#load1').click(function(){
 // redirect here with query param
  window.location = "/page2.html" + "?usename=" + "some name"
});


// Page 2

$(function() {
  // get data
  const username  = localStorage.getItem("username")
  // simply get query param, can write logic and see other code to get param
  const username = window.location.split("?usename=")[1] 
})
```

Comment: can you please give an example to the first one?

Comment: Will update soon.!

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith"); would be better.

Comment: yeah! depends, if u want data should be crlear on session.